# Почему последний символ стирается?

Tags: php

```html
<?php

if ($module == 'register' and $_POST['enter']) {

$_POST['name'] = FormChars($_POST['name']);
$_POST['login'] = FormChars($_POST['login']);
$_POST['email'] = FormChars($_POST['email']);
$_POST['password'] = GenPass(FormChars($_POST['password']), $_POST['login']);

if (!$_POST['login'] or !$_POST['password'] or !$_POST['name'] or !$_POST['email']) MessageSend(1,'Невозможно обработать форму.');

$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$_POST[login]'"));
if($Row['login']) exit('Логин <b>'.$_POST['login'].'</b> уже используется.');

$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$_POST[email]'"));
if($Row['email']) exit('Email <b>'.$_POST['email'].'</b> уже используется.');

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `name`, `regdate`, `email`, `avatar`, `country`) VALUES ('$_POST[login]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[name]', NOW(), '$_POST[email]', 0, 0)");




$code = base64_encode($_POST['email']);
$activationLink = 'http://forum/account/activate/code/' . urlencode($code);
mail($_POST['email'], 'Регистрация на Web-platform', 'Ссылка для активации: ' . $activationLink, 'From: Web-platform');
MessageSend(3, 'Регистрация аккаунта успешно завершена, на указанный email адрес <b>'.$_POST['email'].'</b> отправленно письмо о подтверждении регистрации.');
}

else if ($module == 'activate' and $param['code']) {
    if (!$_SESSION['USER_ACTIVE_EMAIL']) {
        $Email = base64_decode(substr($param['code'], 5) .substr($param['code'], 0, 5));
        if (strpos($Email, '@') !== false) {
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$Email'");
            $_SESSION['USER_ACTIVE_EMAIL'] = $Email;
            MessageSend(1, 'Email <b>'.$Email.' подтвержден.</b>', '/login');
        } else {
            MessageSend(1, 'Email адрес не подтвержден.', '/login');
        }
    } else {
        MessageSend(1, 'Email адрес <b>'.$_SESSION['USER_ACTIVE_EMAIL'].'</b> уже подтвержден.', '/login');
    }
}


?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть система регистрации через PHP, где пользователи могут зарегистрироваться и получить электронное письмо для активации учётной записи. Однако у меня возникает проблема: последний символ электронной почты обрезается, что приводит к ошибке при подтверждении адреса электронной почты.

Comment: 1) Код полон sql-инъекций, такой сайт взломают за пять секунд если захотят

Comment: 2) Вы в качестве кода просто кодируете email в base64? Вы же понимаете, что злоумышленник сможет сделать то же самое и активировать какую угодно почту даже не имея доступа к этой почте?

Comment: 3) Что за странные манипуляции с base64 и substr, зачем? Вы в процессе этих манипуляций и потеряли одну букву, судя по всему